# Simple list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want a dictionary of files:

```
files = [files for (subdir, dirs, files) in os.walk(rootdir)]
```

But I get,

```
files = [['filename1', 'filename2']]
```

when I want

```
files = ['filename1', 'filename2']
```

How do I prevent looping through that tuple? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Comment: Also [Making a flat list out of list of lists in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: forget my files = [f for f in files for (subdir, dirs, files) in os.walk(rootdir)] I think that there are many side effects. I will delete the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of these work:

```
[f for (subdir, dirs, files) in os.walk(rootdir) for f in files]

sum([files for (subdir, dirs, files) in os.walk(rootdir)], [])
```

Sample output:

```
$ find /tmp/test
/tmp/test
/tmp/test/subdir1
/tmp/test/subdir1/file1
/tmp/test/subdir2
/tmp/test/subdir2/file2
$ python
>>> import os
>>> rootdir = "/tmp/test"
>>> [f for (subdir, dirs, files) in os.walk(rootdir) for f in files]
['file1', 'file2']
>>> sum([files for (subdir, dirs, files) in os.walk(rootdir)], [])
['file1', 'file2']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (subdir, dirs, f) in os.walk(rootdir): files.extend(f)
```

Comment: And before this `files = []`.

Answer (score 2):

```
files = [filename for (subdir, dirs, files) in os.walk(rootdir) for filename in files]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, glob

files = [file for file in glob.glob('*') if os.path.isfile(file)]
```

if your files have extensions, then even simpler:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('*.*')
```